# What is AssetMetaCheck?

Tags: rust, bevy

I am reading https://github.com/PraxTube/magus-parvus.

https://github.com/PraxTube/magus-parvus/blob/e91e2428d7e63abee6c400320256185315fbb219/src/main.rs#L36

```rust
.insert_resource(AssetMetaCheck::Never)
```

I am not sure what this means.

I looked at https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/asset/enum.AssetMetaCheck.html

> Configures how / if meta files will be checked. If an asset’s meta file is not checked, the default meta for the asset will be used.

> Never check if assets have meta files and always use the default meta. If meta files exist, they will be ignored and the default meta will be used.

It only says this.

What does it mean by "meta files" here?

Comment: Does the documentation of [AssetMeta](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/asset/meta/struct.AssetMeta.html) help you? Here is a [meta file](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/examples/asset/processing/assets/a.cool.ron.meta).